# Algorithm efficiency analyze

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I need some help with a task given in lecture today;

Given algorithm of O(n∙log n). 
n = 2048 elements runs on a specific computer on 11 sec. How long time will the same algorithm use one the same computer with n = 8192 elements?

Im not really sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: There is really no way to knowing it. For example, maybe n=2048 elements fits entirely in cache, and n=8192 doesn't, and will require many cache fills.

Comment: (Disclaimer, I am going to downvote any answer that is going to assume same constants for n=8192 and n=2048, and base running time on it)

Comment: I think we are looking for a simple formula here. I dont think we should bother with cache and "other" things.

Comment: @amit feel free to downvote my answer. Does it help KimR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you teacher wants from you is to solve this system of equation:
x*2048*log(2^11) = 11
x*4*2048*log(2^13) = y

where:
2048 = 2^11
8192 = 2^13 = 4*2048
x is some cost of processing of an operation, it is the same in the both cases because the computer is the same

y=52 is your answer.
Certainly you might say that the time depends on the hardware or some other things, but I'm sure it is not the subject of your classes.